# Screen stuck when comes back from background state

Tags: bug, android-app

Since I updated the lastest version (*1.0.30*), I've got often a white screen when I reselect the app from the Recents Tasks and it is stuck (and sometimes at start). I cannot see the menu or something else; just the logo, the actionbar and a white background. I always must to restart the app (swipe out from recent list). This had never occurred on lower versions. Is this a known bug or a local issue from my device?

*version: 1.0.30

SDK: 4.4.2*

*Screenshot:*

[image: Issue white screen app stuck]

Comment: I believe I had this problem before on 1.0.29 (Nexus 4, Android 4.4.2 by the way), but now I can't reproduce it and the problem seems intermittent. I don't know if it's related to slow network or not.